# How to hide ordered list item's content while keeping the marker via CSS?

Tags: html, css

We use ordered list to show the steps in the order process:

```
<ol>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li class="active">Customer</li>
  <li>Payment</li>
</ol>
```

which is styled as follows on the desktop:

```
1. Products > 2. Customer > 3. Payment
```

When there is not enough horizontal space, we would like to condense it to (presuming the Customer is the current step):

```
1. > 2. Customer > 3.
```

The best way we found up to now, is by adding an artifical spans and hiding them on narrow screens:

```
<ol>
  <li><span>Products</span></li>
  <li class="active"><span>Customer</span></li>
  <li><span>Payment</span></li>
</ol>
```

It is possible to hide the texts even without the spans? How?

PS: Supporting modern browsers (Edge Chromium, Chrome, Safari, Firefox) in recent versions is enough - we do not need to support MSIE nor legacy browsers.

Comment: Hi, can you please share how you are detecting the current step? Generally we use  that to addClass("active") or someClass {display: block;}  and to hide someClass{display:none;}

Comment: Also how you are detecting there is not enough space?

Comment: We add a class to the current step. The enough space is an artificial width size in the @media as we are not aware of other non-JS way to do determine it. But I am aware these questions are out of scope.

Comment: Here is a link to use calc function for such operations.
https://css-tricks.com/logical-operations-with-css-variables/

You may find your solution in calc examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

font-size can do the trick if you reset if for `::marker`

```css
li:not(.active) {
  font-size:0;
}
li::marker {
  font-size:initial;
}


/**/
ol li{
  float:left;
  padding-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li class="active">Customer</li>
  <li>Payment</li>
</ol>
```